# Can't parse XML on Webdav single folder

Tags: xml, macos, webdav

Mounting webdav. All folders open from Forklift, Finder, Transmit and Cyberduck except one folder.

Folder in question

- Forklift cannot open. Error is "The item can't be opened. Can't parse XML"
- Finder opens but shows zero contents.
- Transmit cannot open. Error is "Could not retrieve file listing for “folder_name”. XML parse error at line 157: not well-formed (invalid token)"
- Cyberduck cannot open. Error is "Listing directory failed. Status code: 207, reason phrase: Not a valid DAV response (207 Multi-Status). Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance."

This issue does not arise when mounting from old PPC Macs running Tiger.

Not techie but willing to do some terminal work or whatever is needed.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Mac OS 10.13.6
Server software Rumpus 9.0.6

Have not tried anything as yet. Hoping for some directions.

Comment: What is the folder name? How does it differ from others?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. It was actually a sub-folder name that appeared corrupted or named with alphanumeric disallowed character!

Created dummy folder and switch contents narrowed it down to faulty sub-folder name.

Thanks for responding.